# Fail2ban random restarts when banning ip

Tags: centos, iptables

I have been running fail2ban on my server for a while without any problems but have recently seen fail2ban restart randomly. After some looking in my logs I noticed that the restarts occur when ever someone gets banned.

So every time someone gets banned the fail2ban server restarts.

Here are a couple of logs.

```
2012-03-23 00:58:39,025 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [dovecot] Ban xx.xx.xx.xx (ip removed)
```

What I have been able to find out is that the fail2ban bans the IP and then it restarts and the only error I can find is.

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found.
```

Iptables is present and running - and I can issue any commands without iptables failing or fail2ban crashing.

Please let me know if you have any idea and if you would need the fail2ban config files

System Information:

- Centos 5.8
- Fail2ban 0.8.2
- Iptables 1.3.5

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable iptable module in your kernel.

Run `modprobe ip_tables`